# Can't Boot EDD information not available

Tags: bios

Recently, I decided to dual boot my Mac with Ubuntu 12.04 beta2. Not sure what I changed, but now I can't boot into Ubuntu, a live cd, or OS X. When I try to boot Ubuntu in recovery mode (as for some reasion I can access the grub menu), the last two lines say:

```
[    1.160316] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found

[    1.160381] EDD information not available.
```

Am I able to recover my computer?

Comment: Recently had the same problem. Gnome-shell crashed on me, making the UI unusuable, so I did a hard reboot, and got the same error...

Comment: Happened to me on Ubuntu 12.04 stable, not beta. Tried nolapic, acpi=off and edd=on in grub (and combinations of those options, as suggested on ubuntu forums). I've managed to get to mounting root filesystem failed. It's a very strange issue.

Answer (score 3):

Reset your Macbook PMU. At least on my model this can be done by, having it turned off, pressing: Cmd + Alt + Ctrl + Shift while pressing the Power button.

I've just had this issue, and it got fixed by doing this

Comment: Holy crap. This actually worked. Pressing those buttons has no immediate effect (the laptop doesn't power on or anything), but afterwards when I pressed only the powerbutton, it booted up correctly. Thanks.